# Why the program gives wrong output?

Tags: java, while-loop, output, biginteger

```
BigInteger p = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger m = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger j = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger n = new BigInteger("3");
BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
while (m.compareTo(n) == -1) {
    while (j.compareTo(n) == -1) {
        p = m.multiply(j);
        System.out.println("m=" + m + " j=" + j + " p=" + p);
        j = j.add(one);
    }
    m = m.add(one);
}
```

Why the output is

```
m=1 j=1 p=1  
m=1 j=2 p=2
```

Shouldn't it be

```
m=1 j=1 p=1  
m=1 j=2 p=2  
m=2 j=1 p=1  
m=2 j=2 p=2
```

?

Comment: You should not be working on your homework in the small hours of the morning.  No wonder you are making silly mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Why would `j` revert from 2 to 1? You are only ever adding to it.

Comment: Oh, I simply forgot to set the value of j to 1 which was my intention and thought I've done that. Thanks a lot. I needed to detect my problem quickly.